# fixed div does not get pushed up by keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I am trying to put a bottom-div, as its name says, fixed on the most bottom of the div, and it should be pushed up when the keyboard is open ( above the keyboard, as now the viewport height should change). However, the problem is that this does not happen. I also know that this is quite the opposite of a lot of people's problem, but somehow, this is not happening for me.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
    <div className="custom-modal">
      <div className="modal-content">
        {/* Your modal content goes here */}
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Modal body content</p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter text" />
      </div>
      <div className="bottom-div">
        {/* Your bottom div content */}
        <button>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```css
.custom-modal {
  position: relative;
 
}



.bottom-div {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff; 
 
}
```

check this  [code pen here](https://codepen.io/vwjvvsoy-the-bashful/pen/dywKMVy)

**EDIT**:
Now tested it on `samsung internet for android` browser, and it seems that it works as intended, so could Chrome be the cause of this problem?

**EDIT 2**
After some digging, it seems that, indeed, the problem was how Chrome on Android is using OSK (OnScreen Keyboard) combined with resize behaviour of Layout Viewport and Visual Viewport. as stated:

> As of Chrome 108, Chrome on Android will adjust its viewport resize behavior to no longer resize the Layout Viewport when the on-screen keyboard is shown.

So, to get back to that `resize` behaviour, all I had to do was writing this in my index.html:

```
<meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 interactive-widget=resizes-content"
    />
```

Now the question arises: Is this a good solution? It seems to have fixed my problem, but would this be a cross-browser problem? As stated on official page:

> This will align the behavior of Chrome on Android with that of Chrome on iOS, iPadOS, Windows, and CrOS, Safari on iOS and iPadOS, and Edge on iOS, iPadOS, and Windows.

So going to modify this would mean that cross browser would work differently?

Link for refference: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/viewport-resize-behavior/#side-effects-of-each-behavior

**EDIT 3**:
As suspected, on safari and chrome for ios, the behaviour remains the same ( the fixed div does not go up, as the layout is not resized when keyboard shows up ). Tested on Iphone 12 and Iphone 12 pro, both on Chrome and Safari. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Why do you have bottom:100%? That should make the bottom of that element be at the top of its parent. Could you create a runnable snippet which we can run on e.g. a real IOS device to see the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Corrected that. Also put a [codepen link](https://codepen.io/vwjvvsoy-the-bashful/pen/dywKMVy)

Comment: The problem seems to be that on mobile, ( Android Chrome ) the viewport size does not change? When focusing the input (as keyboard shows up), no changes are made to the positon of the bottom-div

Comment: Afraid I don't have an Android device to hand to test. Your codepen works fine on my IOS devices.

Comment: It seems to have been a problem with the default behaviour of Android chrome. Strange enough tho, I recently used same fixed behaviour on a different project and it didnt have this problem

Comment: @AHaworth as strange as it looks, now  the problem comes on iOS, at least for iphone 12 and 12 pro. It seems that for these, the layout is not changed when the keyboard is shown. Any guesses on a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `bottom` value to `0` so that it's fixed to the bottom of the viewport.

```
.bottom-div {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;    /* Corrected this value */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

This change will ensure that the bottom-div is fixed to the bottom of the viewport.

Comment: I tried that, but it makes no difference. The bottom-div doesn't get pushed up when the keyboard is shown.